# How can I make my application installer is trusted app in Mac OS(Catalina)?

Tags: macos, qt, installation, code-signing, trusted-application

I have created an application installer using Qt ifw for installing my custom application in Mac OS(Catalina). But when try to install it, Mac OS says it cannot be open since app from unidentified developer. I know that by code signing I can do that by publishing through app store. But is there any other possible way to simply prompt the user and add my app as "trusted" programatically?

Comment: I doubt it, as that would render the whole codesigning+notarizing process pointless.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at https://skyronic.com/2019/07/app-notarization-for-qt-applications/ to see how you can make your app notarized.

Comment: @Smek its worked bro. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Smek That link is not accessible anymore. oh man!! any idea?

Comment: @RajeeshRaveendran, I'm sorry no idea. Maybe this post helps https://forum.qt.io/topic/96652/how-to-notarize-qt-application-on-macos/2